# SpyMemcached : How to implements "isEmpty()", "size()" and "clear()" methods?

Tags: java, spymemcached

I am using the Spymemcached [BaseCacheMap](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/spymemcached-2.8.7/net/spy/memcached/BaseCacheMap.html) class to get information about cached objects.

However these methods are not implemented or returns wrong values :

```java
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
  }

  public int size() {
    return 0;
  }

  public void clear() {
    // TODO: Support a rolling key generation.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
```

Have you got any idea about getting the right results?

**HINT** :

The **MemcachedClient** might be useful, but I don't know how to do.